# delete link with dropzone

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone

i´m traying to do `a href` with dropzone when i uploading a file i can delete my file or if i have one, also i´ll can remove it. for example:

i have this:

[image]

Also i have a dropzone with img and there i can delete image, but href that contain, it have this link: `<a class="dz-remove" href="javascript:undefined;" data-dz-remove="">Remove file</a>` i don´t understan how it´s delete this image. I need to do the same but with my video. My actual code is:

```
let previewVideo = $("<div class='dropzone dz-preview dz-image preview-video'></div>");
let imgVideo = $("<img class='icon-video' id='video-image'/>");
let imgURL = "{{ asset('images/icons/icon-video.png') }}";
let size = var15671147011688676454bleVideo["size"] / 1024 / 1024;
let type = var15671147011688676454bleVideo["collection_name"];
                                

$(".dz-default.dz-message").replaceWith(previewVideo);
$('.preview-video').append(imgVideo);
$("#video-image").attr('src', imgURL);
$(".preview-video").append("<div class='dz-details' id='details'></div>");
$("#details").append("<div class='dz-size'></div>")
$(".dz-size").append("<span class='data-dz-size'></span>");
$(".data-dz-size").append(size.toFixed(2) + "MB");
$(".preview-video").append("<div class='dz-size' id='type'></div>");
$("#type").append("<span class='data-dz-size' id='nameVideo'></span>");
$("#nameVideo").append(type);

$('#nameVideo').after("<a class='dz-remove'>Remove file</a>");
```

i was traying add `href="javascript:undefined;" data-dz-remove=""` in my `ahref` but nothing. In code have a function `removedfile` that is:

```
removedfile: function (file) {
                            alert("llego");
                            dzRemoveFile(
                                file, var15671147011688676454bleVideo, '{!! url("panel/restaurants/remove-media") !!}',
                                'video', '{!! isset($restaurant) ? $restaurant->id : 0 !!}', '{!! url("panel/uploads/clear") !!}', '{!! csrf_token() !!}'
                            );
                        }
```

but if i do onClick(this.removedfile(file)) file is not defined or removedfile is not defined or removed is not a function....

i don´t know how i can to do this.

Thanks for help

Comment: Hi, can you make your code runnable ?

Comment: @Swati i don´t know how i can to do this. because form it automatically generate with laravel, and its dificult to do in runable code